# Integrate jnlp into existing eclipse RCP environment?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

new to eclipse RCP environment. I have a Webstart Apps/jnlp  that I would like to add into an already made rcp client. Was wondering if It was possible to integrate it into the RCP so it will appear under the menu toolbar so if it was clicked from the menu upon the jnlp will load into the browser. How will I go about doing that, would it need to be as a plug-in?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what version of eclipse are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it, but how about writing a simple plugin with a menu contribution, command assiciated with that menu would open somewhere small viewpart with Browser component and finally, that Browser component would get the resource you need?